# nginx: the try_files equivalent of a rewrite directive won't work

Tags: nginx

Having a file on `/GET-cache/contact.html` and requesting the URI `/contact`, with this directive, it works as expected:

```
if (-f $document_root/$request_method-cache$uri.html) {
  rewrite (.*) /GET-cache/$1.html break;
}
```

This one doesn't:

```
try_files $request_method-cache$uri.html @backend;
```

Using `$document_root` in the `try_files` directive doesn't work either (what I mean when I say it doesn't work is that the request gets passed up to the backend instead of nginx serving the static file).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a matter of not starting your check with a forward slash. Try this:

`try_files /$request_method-cache$uri.html @backend;`

Nginx applies each argument to try_files to the root directive. So if your root is `/var/www` then it'll check against `var/wwwGET-cache/foo.html`